# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments.. Firebase

Tags: xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, combine

Not sure why i'm getting this.. any suggestions would be grateful!

I ran into issues with my original coding where I had Firebase pod and Firebase Package.. so I started from scratch since that wasnt fixing itself.. now I get this.. and I am at a loss for how to resolve it.

```
static func fetchUsers() -> AnyPublisher<[UserProfile], Error> {
        Future< [UserProfile], Error > { promise in
            self.db.collection("Users")
                .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        promise(.failure(error))
                        return
                    }
                    
                    guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                        promise(.failure(FirebaseError.badSnapshot))
                        return
                    }
                    
                    var users = [UserProfile]()
                    snapshot.documents.forEach { document in
                        print(users.count)
                        
                        if let user = try? document.data(as: UserProfile.self){
                            if users.contains(where: { $0.id == user.id}) {return}
                            users.append(user)
                        }  else {
                            print("Not working")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    promise(.success(users))
                    
                }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

[image: Image of Error]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the syntax you're after:

```
var users = [UserProfile]()

users = snapshot.documents.compactMap { (document) -> UserProfile? in
    if users.contains(where: { $0.id == user.id}) {
        return nil
    } else {
        return try? document.data(as: UserProfile.self)
    }
}
```

Also be aware that when you iterate something in Swift and encounter a false condition on an iteration, `return` will return out of the greater scope, not just that iteration. Therefore, use `continue`.

```
for x in y {
    guard x > 0 else {
        continue // continues loop
    }
    // ...
}
```